# How to scroll left part of the page using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am looking to scrape some jobs from google jobs. Here's the layout:

[image]

I want to scroll the left part of page that lists all the jobs using puppeteer but not able to figure out how. Any ideas?

Here's the scraping link - [google jobs](https://www.google.com/search?q=remote%20jobs%20usa&rlz=1C1CHZN_enIN1021IN1021&oq=remote%20jobs%20usa&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39l2j0i67i650j0i67i131i433i650j0i131i433i512j0i67i650j0i67i131i433i650j0i67i650j0i67i131i433i650.8792j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&ibp=htl;jobs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbpcfnif79AhUxpekKHVrnAfcQudcGKAF6BAgNEC4&sxsrf=APwXEddeE6AA0sc8zlZP4kw8H-Gb0nDUqA:1679987680866#htivrt=jobs&htidocid=gzV71kpsP9YAAAAAAAAAAA%3D%3D&fpstate=tldetail)

Comment: Can you provide the scraped link?

Comment: Here you go - https://www.google.com/search?q=remote+jobs+usa&rlz=1C1CHZN_enIN1021IN1021&oq=remote+jobs+usa&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39l2j0i67i650j0i67i131i433i650j0i131i433i512j0i67i650j0i67i131i433i650j0i67i650j0i67i131i433i650.8792j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&ibp=htl;jobs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbpcfnif79AhUxpekKHVrnAfcQudcGKAF6BAgNEC4&sxsrf=APwXEddeE6AA0sc8zlZP4kw8H-Gb0nDUqA:1679987680866#htivrt=jobs&htidocid=gzV71kpsP9YAAAAAAAAAAA%3D%3D&fpstate=tldetail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just inspect that link and find the true selector of the div on the left side. You will find

```html
<div jsname="CaV2mb" class="zxU94d gws-plugins-horizon-jobs__tl-lvc">
...
</div>
```

Select that with `page.evaulate`, then apply some scrolling. Full code:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async() => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/search?q=remote+jobs+usa&rlz=1C1CHZN_enIN1021IN1021&oq=remote+jobs+usa&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39l2j0i67i650j0i67i131i433i650j0i131i433i512j0i67i650j0i67i131i433i650j0i67i650j0i67i131i433i650.8792j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&ibp=htl;jobs&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbpcfnif79AhUxpekKHVrnAfcQudcGKAF6BAgNEC4&sxsrf=APwXEddeE6AA0sc8zlZP4kw8H-Gb0nDUqA:1679987680866#htivrt=jobs&htidocid=gzV71kpsP9YAAAAAAAAAAA%3D%3D&fpstate=tldetail");
    let target = '.zxU94d.gws-plugins-horizon-jobs__tl-lvc';
    await page.waitForSelector(target);
    let currentJobsCount = 0;
    while (true) {
        await page.evaluate(selector => {
            const scrollableSection = document.querySelector(selector);
            scrollableSection.scrollTo({ top: scrollableSection.scrollHeight });
        }, target);
        await page.waitForTimeout(1500); // change this depends on your netork connection
        let availableJobsCount = (await page.$$('.iFjolb.gws-plugins-horizon-jobs__li-ed')).length;
        if (currentJobsCount == availableJobsCount) {
            break;
        } else {
            currentJobsCount = availableJobsCount;
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you. But it only scrolls once. How can I make it to keep scrolling until I hit the end?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with the logic: *When scroll end, check jobs count if same with previous jobs count*. Please see the updated answer.